# How to transfer Database to another Database via WCF

Tags: sql, database, wcf, sql-server-2008

hallo,

How can i transfer the table Command via WCF ?

i have a idee: 
in client side : 
using normal SQL syntax: SELECT * FROM COMMAND then wrap it the result into List or IeNumerable or another type of collection and then use WCF List GetCommand ()

and in server side :
call  WCF List GetCommand () then  loop the collection use INSERT INTO COMMAND...into table Command

is that a good idea ? if not could you give me a hints ?

Thanx you in advance,
Stev

PS: i just want to transfer specific data:
SELECT * FROM COMMAND WHERE REGION_CLIENT = 345 (not all database)

Comment: Please improve the clarity of your question. I don't understand it.

Comment: Probably not because there are dedicated database migration/sync tools out there for most mainstream databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you are tring to do is to transfer data from a local client database to the server, you should use the microsoft sync framework, see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb736753